# Creating a file format to deal with a comma in a string

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I'm trying to import a csv file into Snowflake.
I created a file format as usual but I quickly found out that one of the values had a comma which causing an error.

For example,

```
1234, John, male, Stack,
1235, Kati, female, Overflow,
1236, Rudy, male, Stack,Overflow
```

Which results to this

```
| ID | Name | String1 | String 2| {NULL} |
|----------------------------------------|
|1234| John |   male  |  Stack  |        |
|1235| Kati |  female | Overflow|        |
|1236| Rudy |   male  |  Stack  |Overflow|
```

But I want is this:

```
| ID | Name | String1 |   String 2   |
|------------------------------------|
|1234| John |   male  |     Stack    |
|1235| Kati |  female |   Overflow   |
|1236| Rudy |   male  |Stack,Overflow|
```

I created a file format like this below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FILE FORMAT format_example 
    TYPE = CSV 
    COMPRESSION = AUTO 
    FIELD_DELIMITER = ',' 
    SKIP_HEADER = 1 
    DATE_FORMAT = "DD-MON-YYYY" 
    FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '"' 
    EMPTY_FIELD_AS_NULL = TRUE
```

What should I do? Is there a way for me get the desired outcome?
Or is there a way to wrap the strings in quotations in Snowflake?

Comment: One way is to escape char in file - like 1236, Rudy, male, Stack\,Overflow

Comment: Another trick in case your delimiter is using space, then try using this in file_format - FIELD_DELIMITER = ', ' (notice space after comma)

Comment: I suggest you re-create your file as tab separated, and use \t as field delimiter in your file format. Using a delimiter that could easily be part of your data will make your upload processes unnecessarily complex.

Comment: If the data is enclosed in double quotes, (ex: 1236, "Rudy", "male", "Stack,Overflow"), then using FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '"'  will load it as Stack,Overflow. You can try exporting the file with quotes and the above file format will work.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a problem with a malformed CSV, if you can't change it just ingest the whole row and then split inside Snowflake:

```sql
with data as (
    select '1236, Rudy, male, Stack,Overflow' x
    union all select '1234, John, male, Stack,'
    union all select '1235, Kati, female, Overflow,'
)

select regexp_substr(x, '[^,]*')
    , regexp_substr(x, '[^,]+', 1, 2)
    , regexp_substr(x, '[^,]+', 1, 3)
    , regexp_substr(x, '[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,(.*[^,])', 1,1,'',1)
from data
```

[image]

For more complex cases you could use a CSV parser in JS or Java.

Comment: Thank you! This works but could you explain the last line? I am a little confused with (.*[^,])', 1,1,'',1)

Comment: The last one looks for 3 commas, then gives you everything after it (except the last comma, if there's one)